# How to remove author, category, and date from all posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How to remove author and post date from post archive and single post in wordpress.. Can anyone help me in this regard. i use some css but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this  `<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>` and use  `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>`  in single.php

Comment: can i achieve this by any plugin and css... i am afraid of diing this in php because sometimes site goes blank while do something with php code of theme