# How to remove Author, Date, and Category from Wordpress search results (Divi theme)

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]

I want to remove the highlighted from my **search results** and the **posts** too.

This did not help because that code to replace is not in my single.php file:

[How to remove author, category, and date from all posts in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312055/how-to-remove-author-category-and-date-from-all-posts-in-wordpress)

Comment: Can you provide code from your search.php and single.php files? Otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searched some more and found the answer. **It depends on the theme you are using**.
If you are using ElegantTheme's Divi like me...

**To change search results:**
Go to theme option > layout tab > general tab > Post info section
and check the author.

**To change posts:**
Go to theme option > layout tab > single post layout > Post info section
and check the author.

[image]

Comment: Glad to see that you're helping yourself by searching for the right resource. But just a heads up, when you ask for help (anywhere) do include all the nitty gritty details.